# Detecting when FLVPlayback source is bad or not found

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flvplayback

I'm totally at a loss as to how to detect if my instance of FLVPlayback component has been handed a source that either doesn't exist or it can't play for one reason or another.

I've attached handlers to every event I can think of... specifically...

```
        videoPlayer.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, vidEnd);
        videoPlayer.addEventListener(VideoEvent.READY, vidStart);
        videoPlayer.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYHEAD_UPDATE, vidMoved);         
        videoPlayer.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);           
        videoPlayer.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
```

But none of those fire when the clip is missing or corrupted.

I also tried this:

```
            try{
                videoPlayer.source = "http://localhost:18888/" + folder + "/" + nextUrl;
            }catch(e:VideoError){
                trace("http://localhost:18888/" + folder + "/" + nextUrl + " couldn't be found");
                playNextItem();
            }
```

But that doesn't work either.  I'm totally stumped.  What's the correct way to do this?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, don't use FLVPlayback, because it does too many "magic" things behind the scenes and is a bit buggy. It's basically just a wrapper around the `VideoPlayer` class.

If you have to use FLVPlayback, you can access the VideoPlayer being wrapped with `FLVPlayback.getVideoPlayer`, then listen to `VideoState.STATE_CHANGE` and monitor `VideoPlayer.state`. If it's `VideoState.CONNECTION_ERROR`, it means your video feed cannot be loaded or played.